# Textbox shows WaterMarkText of TextBoxWatermarkExtender if I press alt + tab in Mozilla

Tags: asp.net

here is my code ...
Its work fine if I am on same page but if my focus is on accountinginfo textbox and I pressed the "alt + tab" (swith the window) then if I come to the same page the textbox shows the WaterMarkText in textbox (with focus) i.e. with textbox CSS

```
<asp:TextBox ID="accountinginfo" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="450px" Height="80" CssClass="textfield100percaps"></asp:TextBox>

<act:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="accinfo" runat="server" TargetControlID="accountinginfo" Enabled="true" WatermarkText="Accounting Information" WatermarkCssClass="watermarkOn" />
```